# My buttons wont appear until i hover over it with my mouse

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

i have this problem and yes i saw that other people had the problem to but i not realy able to compare there code to mine and see the problem that way so i hope u can help me.

i use intellij to write my code and use there gui desinger to make gui's but when i added a button i didnt get it to display untill i hover it with a mouse and the possitions are wrong and i cant realy get it to work. here are the classes
    // this is the jpanel class
    public class paintMenu extends JPanel{

```
public JPanel menuPanel;
public JButton newGameButt;
public JButton loadGameButt;
public JButton helpbutt;
public JButton optionsButt;
public JButton info;
public JButton quitButt;

public paintMenu(){

    add(newGameButt);
    add(loadGameButt);
    add(helpbutt);
    add(info);
    add(optionsButt);
    add(quitButt);
    setVisible(true);


}

//this is de jframe class 
public class jframepainter extends JFrame {

paintMenu menupaint = new paintMenu();

public jframepainter(){


    //main frame settings
    setTitle("Kingdom V " + Reference.version);
    setSize(Reference.width, Reference.height);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(Kingdom.vissible);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //draw jpnael
    getContentPane().add(menupaint);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the JFrame to visible after you add your JPanel to it. Also you may want to call this.pack() after you add your JPanel.

```
//main frame settings
setTitle("Kingdom V " + Reference.version);
setSize(Reference.width, Reference.height);
setResizable(false);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//draw jpnael
getContentPane().add(menupaint);  //Moved this before setting Visible
this.pack();                      // call pack before setting visible
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(Kingdom.vissible);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the Kingdom class is, but i can assume that vissible is a typo and may be causing a compile-time error. You didn't clearly describe your problem.

Comment: Kingdom is the main class and Kingdom.vissible is set to true in that class